# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(DataSnapshot) -> Void'

Tags: swift

I have following error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()'
>   to non-throwing function type '(DataSnapshot) -> Void'

```
func getUserList() throws {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("User").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let keys = value?.allKeys

        for key in keys! {
        let dict = value?[key] as? NSDictionary
        let user = User.init(name: dict?["Name"] as? String ?? "", selected: dict?["Selected"] as? String ?? "")
        let viewUser = ViewUser.init(user: user)
            self.data.append(viewUser)

            debugPrint(user ?? "")
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        if value?.count == 0 {
            throw UserError.Empty
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing an error in the completion block. This is not possible and causes the error.

The return value of the closure is not related to the return value of the enclosing function – strictly spoken `throws` is not a return value but is affected, too.

To be able to return something from the closure you have to implement a completion block rather than `throws`

```
func getUserList(completion : (Error?) -> ())
```

and use it

```
completion(value.isEmpty ? UserError.Empty : nil)
```

---

Side-note: You are using too many question and exclamation marks. Use optional binding to unwrap optionals for example (and use Swift native collection types)

```
if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
   for key in value.keys { ...
```